# Spring boot, Thymeleaf, Ajax, get null object from ajax

Tags: ajax, spring, thymeleaf

I want to get an object from the form right away in ajax. Where object has name, booleans. But after the transfer, in Controller for some reason it comes with null fields.

Here HTML code:

```
<form id="profileStats" name="profileStats" action="#" th:action="@{/profile/{id}}" th:object="${profileStats}"
    method="get">
   <div class="photo">
     <img src="./static/img/icon.ico" th:src="*{photoPath}" width="200px" height="200px"/>
   </div>
   <div class="info">
   </div>
</form>
```

Controller, where i send object to HTML:

```
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
  public String getProfile(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model) {
    ProfileStats stats = new ProfileStats(userClient.getClient());

    model.addAttribute("profileStats", stats);

    return "profile";
  }
```

Ajax, where i send object from HTML to Controller:

```
    function setStatistic() {
        var $form = $('#profileStats');
    
        $.ajax({
          url: window.location.pathname + '/progress',
          method: 'GET',
          cache: false,
          data: $form.serialize(),
          success: function (data) {
            $('.info').html(data);
    
            if (data.search("done") >= 0) {
              stopProgress();
            }
          },
          error: function (e) {
            console.log("error", e)
          }
        });
      }
```

Controller, where i get object from AJAX:

```
  @GetMapping("/{id}/progress")
  public ModelAndView getProgress(@ModelAttribute("profileStats") ProfileStats stats) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView;

    if (stats.isHaveAllMessage()) {
      // HERE I GET NULL EXCEPTION
    }

    return modelAndView;
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

In debugging console.log($form.serialize()) I get nothing

Comment: hi there, where are you calling the method `setStatistic`? and have you tried to serialize the form explicitly from a debug console? like so `$('#profileStats').serialize()`?

Comment: @atish.s I call method `window.onload = setStatistic()`. Yes, i wrote about it in the end of question. I get nothing

Comment: By explicitly I meant to inspect the page after it has loaded and execute `$('#profileStats').serialize()` in the debug console to see the results or the errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `ModelAttribute` and `ModelAndView` in your `GetMapping` method if you want to use this from an AJAX call.

Use a `@RequestBody` and return a `@ResponseBody` instead. And in your AJAX call, create JSON from the form data to send and receive.

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/{id}/progress")
public ProgressResponse getProgress(@PathVariable("id) String id, @RequestBody ProfileStatsRequestBody requestBody) {
  //.. do whatever needs to be done here
  return new ProgressResponse(...)
}
```

With `ProgressResponse` and `ProfileStatsRequestBody` 2 new classes that map onto the JSON you want to send/receive.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to include some fields as part of the form so Spring can do the mapping to the respective fields in the `ProfileStats` object. See the example in here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Comment: This is not suitable for me, since I do not send the form, but keep a counter that will be updated in the background every second. This is the idea of ​ajax